# Julia: Matrix visualization in a heatmap

Tags: matrix, plot, julia, heatmap

I would like to visualize a matrix by using heatmap figure.
Imagine like we divide it into four small areas or four small matrice in which each small matrix we have its own constraints/conditions for the (x,y) values. Please have a look at the followind code.

My problem is instead of having a curve/line region for the values in the heatmap, it automatically computes the values of all constraints/conditions and then it became wrong figure (see the heatmap).

My first try: the wrong figure but it was my first try, but at least it has entry values for matrix
please have a look this heatmap:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nWBi.png)

My second try: it produces nothing for 3/4 of the matrix, so it is not good to plot though.

My expectation is to get the heatmap that shows the region as in this line figure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSjG7.png)

Potential solutions come to my mind is adding the function instead of condition-which-are-already-computed-by-Julia since I expected to get the curve/line from the function. Please let me know your comments.

I send you the code and the type of function to check here:

**My first try: with the wrong expectation:**

```
using Plots

function W(x, y, g, d, ϕ, c, α, s)
if x <= c/ϕ && y <= c/ϕ
p_1 = x + g * x * (1 - x) - d * (x - y) - α*x
p_2 = y + g * y * (1 - y) - d * (y - x) - α*y
return 1 - p_1 + 1 - p_2

    elseif x >= c/ϕ && y <= c/ϕ 
        p_1 = x + g * x * (1 - x) - d * (x - y) - ϕ*x - α*x
        p_2 = y + g * y * (1 - y) - d * (y - x) - α*y
        return 1 - p_1 - c  + 1 - p_2 
    
    elseif x <= c/ϕ && y >= c/ϕ 
        p_1 = x + g * x * (1 - x) - d * (x - y) - α*x
        p_2 = y + g * y * (1 - y) - d * (y - x) - ϕ*y - α*y
        return 1 - p_1 + 1 - p_2 - c
    
    elseif x >= c/ϕ && y >= c/ϕ && x<= 0.79 && y<= 0.79 ### I replaces the satisfied values of inequality 
        p_1 = x + g * x * (1 - x) - d * (x - y) - ϕ*x - α*x
        p_2 = y + g * y * (1 - y) - d * (y - x) - ϕ*y - α*y
        return 1 - p_1 - c + 1 - p_2 - c
    
    elseif x >= 0.79 && y >= c/ϕ  
        p_1 = x + g * x * (1 - x) - d * (x - y) - ϕ*x - α*x
        p_2 = y + g * y * (1 - y) - d * (y - x) - ϕ*y - α*y
        return s + 1 - p_2 - c
    
    elseif x >= c/ϕ && y >= 0.79 
        p_1 = x + g * x * (1 - x) - d * (x - y) - ϕ*x - α*x
        p_2 = y + g * y * (1 - y) - d * (y - x) - ϕ*y - α*y
        return 1 - p_1 - c + s
    
    elseif x >= 0.79 && y >=0.79
        p_1 = x + g * x * (1 - x) - d * (x - y) - ϕ*x - α*x
        p_2 = y + g * y * (1 - y) - d * (y - x) - ϕ*y - α*y
        return ((1 - p_1 - c + s) + (s + 1 - p_2 - c))/2
    end

end

g = 0.5
d = 0.25
c = 0.2
ϕ = 0.4
α = 0.25
s = 0.3

x_vals = range(0, stop = 1, length = 100)
y_vals = range(0, stop = 1, length = 100)

z = [W(x, y, g, d, ϕ, c, α, s) for x in x_vals, y in y_vals\]

pyplot()
fig = heatmap(x_vals, y_vals, z, xlabel = "P1", ylabel = "P2",
zlabel = "", title = "Total Payoff", color = :viridis, aspect_ratio=:equal)
```

**My second try: It produces the wrong matrix :( **

```
using Plots

function W(x, y, g, d, ϕ, c, α, s)
condition_3 = (1/d)*(1 - s - c) - (1/d)*(1 + g - d - ϕ)*x - (g/d)x^2
condition_4 = (1/d)*(1 - s - c) - (1/d)(1 + g - d - ϕ)*y - (g/d)y^2
condition_31 = (1/d)*(1 - s - c) - (1/d)(1 + g - d - ϕ - (α/2))*x - (g/d)x^2
condition_41 = (1/d)*(1 - s - c) - (1/d)(1 + g - d - ϕ - (α/2))\*y - (g/d)\*y^2

    if x <= c/ϕ && y <= c/ϕ 
        p_1 = x + g * x * (1 - x) - d * (x - y) 
        p_2 = y + g * y * (1 - y) - d * (y - x)
        return 1 - p_1 + 1 - p_2 
    
    elseif x >= c/ϕ && y >= c/ϕ && y <= condition_3 && x <= condition_4 #y <= f(x) && x <= f(y)
        p_1 = x + g * x * (1 - x) - d * (x - y) - ϕ*x
        p_2 = y + g * y * (1 - y) - d * (y - x) - ϕ*y
        return 1 - p_1 - c + 1 - p_2 - c
    
    elseif x <= c/ϕ && y >= c/ϕ && x <= condition_4
        p_1 = x + g * x * (1 - x) - d * (x - y)
        p_2 = y + g * y * (1 - y) - d * (y - x) - ϕ*y
        return 1 - p_1 + 1 - p_2 - c
    
    elseif x >= c/ϕ && y <= c/ϕ && y <= condition_3
        p_1 = x + g * x * (1 - x) - d * (x - y) - ϕ*x
        p_2 = y + g * y * (1 - y) - d * (y - x) 
        return 1 - p_1 - c  + 1 - p_2 
    
    elseif x >= c/ϕ && y >= c/ϕ && y >= condition_3 && x <= condition_41
        p_1 = x + g * x * (1 - x) - d * (x - y)
        p_2 = y + g * y * (1 - y) - d * (y - x) - ϕ*y
        return s + (1 - P_2 - c + ϕ*y + (α/2)*y)
    
    elseif x >= c/ϕ && y >= c/ϕ && y <= condition_31 && x >= condition_4
        p_1 = x + g * x * (1 - x) - d * (x - y) 
        p_2 = y + g * y * (1 - y) - d * (y - x) - ϕ*y
        return (1 - P_1 - c + ϕ*x + (α/2)*x) + s
    end

end

g = 0.5
d = 0.25
c = 0.2
ϕ = 0.4
α = 0.25
s = 0.3

x_vals = range(0, stop = 1, length = 100)
y_vals = range(0, stop = 1, length = 100)

z = [W(x, y, g, d, ϕ, c, α, s) for x in x_vals, y in y_vals\]

fig = heatmap(x_vals, y_vals, z, xlabel = "Pi", ylabel = "Pj",
zlabel = "", title = "Total Payoff", color = :viridis)
```

Comment: Your question needs some clarification. Are you having trouble with plotting or is the problem with the calculation of your matrix?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a problem with the plot based on the matrix, so maybe it is (1) the problem with matrix computation and then leads to (2) problem of plotting wrong heatmap. 

As you see in the figure that contains the lines only (figure 2), I expect to compute the entries of the matrix with the conditions (expect to get the heatmap with the region following the line), but I plotted wrong figure (figure 1 - heatmap attachment). Please let me know your further comment.